# Querying nested object arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a category schema and an example data like below :

```
{
    categories: [], -- array of category object
    id: String,
    name: String
}

{ 
 "id" : 1,
 "name" : "cat1",
 "categories" : [ 
    {
    "id:2,
    "name": "cat2",
    "categories" : [
        {
        "id":3,
        "name": "cat3,
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to get categories by their name, but I can only reach the first level if say something like

```
categories.findOne({"name": "cat1"}) -- returns cat1 correctly
categories.findOne({"name": "cat2"}) -- returns nothing
```

How can I search within subcategories ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact format of data? Are there nested `categories` inside `categories`?

Comment: `categories.findOne({"categories.name": "cat2"})` would do the job, bu it's a bit hardcoding and it will not return if there are `cat2` in the first level (the level of id: 1)

Comment: yes and this is exactly what my problem is :)

Comment: Do you want to find just the category  or category and its child categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [mongoose-mpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-mpath)  package to create tree hierarchy.

Here are the steps:

1-) Create a category schema using this plugin.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const MpathPlugin = require("mongoose-mpath");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

schema.plugin(MpathPlugin);

const Category = mongoose.model("Category", schema);

module.exports = { Category };
```

2-) post route to insert categories with hierarchy:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Category } = require("../models/category");

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, parent } = req.body;

  const category = await Category.create({ name, parent });

  res.status(201).send(category);
});
```

Using this route, create the categories with postman:

Root Category: (it is good to have a ROOT category, root has no parent)

```
{
    "name": "ROOT"
}
```

The response will be like this: (as you see this plugin added a path field internally to maintain hierarchy)

```
{
    "_id": "5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7",
    "name": "ROOT",
    "path": "5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Cat1 category: (note that we set parent field to the root category id which is 5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7)

```
{
    "name": "Cat1",
    "parent": "5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7"
}
```

Result for Cat1:

```
{
    "_id": "5dd95b21997fc53e1ce944a8",
    "name": "Cat1",
    "parent": "5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7",
    "path": "5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7#5dd95b21997fc53e1ce944a8",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Cat11 category: (note that we set parent field to the Cat1 id which is 5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7)

```
{
    "name": "Cat11",
    "parent": "5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7"
}
```

Result for Cat11:

```
{
    "_id": "5dd95b8e997fc53e1ce944aa",
    "name": "Cat11",
    "parent": "5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7",
    "path": "5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7#5dd95b8e997fc53e1ce944aa",
    "__v": 0
}
```

And to find a category by name, you can use the following get route:
(I hard coded category name for simplicity, you cantake category name from req.body or req.query)

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  let category = await Category.findOne({
    name: "Cat11" 
  });

  res.status(200).send(category);
});
```

This will return you the Cat11 category document like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5dd95b8e997fc53e1ce944aa",
    "name": "Cat11",
    "parent": "5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7",
    "path": "5dd95adf997fc53e1ce944a7#5dd95b8e997fc53e1ce944aa",
    "__v": 0
}
```

And if you want to get the children categories of the found category, you can try `mongoose-mpath` methods like getChildrenTree.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to query a specific field with the findOne method, but query methods work at the collection level. In order to query nested fields in documents within a collection, use dot notation.

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/)

the command (in the MongoDB shell) will be something like...

```
db.findOne({"categories.name": "cat2"})
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't know at which level "cat2" is. So it may be "categories.categories.name" and so on. That's why I can't use dot notation.