# how to retrieve n level nested categories tree in mongodb query or via mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i have a mongo collection with n level categrories say

```
ID     category     parentId
1     automobile    null
2     cars          1
3     bikes         1
4     sport car     2
```

I want to retrieve whole tree with following structure is it possible to produce with one recursive query  to find nested children

```
[
 {
  id:1,
  category:automobile,
  children:[
             {
              id:2,
              category:cars,
              parentId:1,
              children:[
                        {
                          id:4,
                          category:sport car,
                          parentId: 2
                        }
                       ]
             },
             {
              id:3,
              category:bikes,
              parentId:1,
             }

           ]
 }
]
```

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59009854/11717458). You can use mongoose-mpath package's getChildrenTree method.

Comment: yes, its easy to implement this feature with materialized path with the help of mongoose-mpath, thank you again

Comment: you are welcome, I appreciate if you can upvote the answer.